# Simplify my Django Query Logic

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a table which looks like this.

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
| id | parent | type    | libTypeId | name                   |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
|  2 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_hvt |
|  5 |      1 | project |         6 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_hvt |
|  8 |      1 | project |        16 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_hvt |
| 11 |      1 | project |        21 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_hvt |
|  3 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_lvt |
|  6 |      1 | project |         6 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_lvt |
|  9 |      1 | project |        16 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_lvt |
| 12 |      1 | project |        21 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_lvt |
|  1 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_svt |
|  4 |      1 | project |         6 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_svt |
|  7 |      1 | project |        16 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_svt |
| 10 |      1 | project |        21 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_svt |
| 13 |      2 | project |         2 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 17 |      2 | project |         4 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 14 |      2 | project |         6 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 18 |      2 | project |        12 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 15 |      2 | project |        16 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 16 |      2 | project |        21 | 065nm_GPIO             |
| 19 |      2 | project |         2 | 065nm_Specialized      |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
```

What I am looking for is a query which results in a list where we get all projects with id = 1 which is sorted by name, libtypeid and the FIRST libtypeid only.

In otherwords I should end up with this:

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
| id | parent | type    | libTypeId | name                   |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
|  2 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_hvt |
|  3 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_lvt |
|  1 |      1 | project |         2 | 1p6m4x0y1z_1.2-1.8_svt |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
```

Now I can get this far but how do I get only the first one??

```
Variant.objects.filter(parent=self.id).order_by('name', 'libtype_id')
```

I then further do this..

```
full = Variant.objects.filter(parent=self.id).order_by('name', 'libtype_id')
names, out = [], []
for v in full:
    if v.name not in names:
       out.append(v)
       names.append(v.name)
return out
```

Much appreciate if someone can clean this up a bit..

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. you want to get the first item from the result set? just use an index.

Comment: akonsu - Yes I want the first unique 'name' in this set - I should end up with three items. can you provide me an example - Thanks

Comment: (Variant.objects.filter(parent=self.id).order_by('name', 'libtype_id')[0]).name is that what you are asking? I still do not understand...

Comment: Do you mean this? Variant.objects.filter(parent=self.id).order_by('name', 'libtype_id')[0]

Comment: No I don't want the first record of the complete set. I want the first record of each subset. The way in which the first set is grouped is by name, followed by libtypeid.  I want the first libtypeid only not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for..

```
class VariantQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def as_single_library_type(self):
        query = self.filter().query
        query.group_by = ['name']
        return QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db, query=query)

class VariantManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return VariantQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

This basically does a default `GROUP BY` which reduces everything to what I need.  Thanks to all who attempted answered!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the question correctly, you need to "group by" your set and return the first row from each group. you need to take a look at aggregation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

something along the lines of

`Variant.objects
    .values('name', 'libtype_id')
    .annotate(min_libtype_id=Min('libtype_id'))
    .filter(parent=self.id)`

**this is untested**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[number]` to the queryset, like:

```
Variant.objects.filter(parent=self.id).order_by('name', 'libtype_id')[0]
```

That returns the first record in the queryset. To get the last one, it would be `[:0]`, the colon reverses the splice.

Comment: No this is the first element of the set.  I want all first subelements of the set.